# No matter what, but the right click is now gone

Tags: touchpad

I recently bought a Huaweii X Mate Pro. For a little time the right click was working, then I left the computer off for says 3/4 days and today in reopening (even restarting).

I installed [Tweaks](https://itsfoss.com/change-scroll-touchpad-ubuntu/#comments) and even tried editing the settings in the 01-input.conf file under the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` folder and the same file (sort of) in the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` folder without success.

The right click method as per the `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method` is set to areas, but it doesn't matter if I change to fingers. The result is still the same.

A system without the right click is not particularly useful. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the terminal output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method`? How did you generally right click before? Two fingers or by tapping the lower-right corner of the touchpad? 

Comment: is set to areas, but fingers doesn't change it too

Comment: Ok I got the problem, apparently the right click only works if the tap to click is enabled. In fact in the tweaks setting, or via terminal, swappping from areas to fingers or the other way round doesn't sort any effect. I can only get the right menu with a two-fingers tap in the middle of the trackpad, which - as I said - it implies the tap-to-click being enabled (a function that I hate, I like clicks to avoid accidental things happening.)

Comment: Indeed, that is how it works - that inconsistency may also be why the setting is not exposed by default - you need to go into Tweaks. Feel free to write your finding up as an answer and accept it - this is perfectly fine on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the problem.

Apparently the right click only works if the `tap to click` is enabled.

In fact in the tweaks setting, or via terminal (`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method`), swappping from `areas` to `fingers` or the other way round doesn't sort any effect.

I could only get the right menu with a two-fingers tap in the middle of the trackpad, which - as I said - it implies the tap-to-click being enabled (a function that I hate, I like clicks to avoid accidental things happening).